# Как вырезать определенный текст в regex?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка  `My {site}` как оставить только site ?
А вот если нужно еще так: `my {zip} i {ooi} выбрать zip и ooi`

Comment: regexp не нужен. strpos + substr определенно решают проблему

Comment: Вот регулярка. Наверное знаете как использовать . `\{.*?\}`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan почему не w+? а именно так

Comment: @Silento разницу между ними не знаете? Можете дать свой вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы извлечь текст между одним символом/подстрокой и *ближайшим к нему* другим символом/подстокой, обычно используется `.*?`, точка с ленивым квантификатором. Если между этими символами/подстроками есть знак перехода на новую строку, нужно использовать модификатор `s` (`DOTALL`, изменяет поведение точки в шаблоне для нахождения символов перехода на новую строку). Чтобы не приходилось добавлять этот модификатор и получить более эффективное выражение, можно прибегнуть к исключающим символьным классам, `[^}]*` — 0 и более символов, отличных от `}`. В случае использования многосимвольной подстроки в качестве начального разделителя такой подход, к сожалению, не сработает.

Кроме того, существует несколько разновидностей шаблонов, извлекающих тексты между двумя фигурными (да и другими) скобками. Рассмотрим варианты, из которых можно выбрать наиболее подходящие для данной и других ситуаций:

- Между ближайшими `{...}` есть любые знаки: [`'~{(.*?)}~s'`](https://regex101.com/r/ciV633/1) / [`'~{([^}]*)}~'`](https://regex101.com/r/ciV633/2)
- Между ближайшими `{...}` есть любые знаки, кроме самих скобок: [`'~{([^{}]*)}~'`](https://regex101.com/r/ciV633/3)
- Между ближайшими `{...}` есть только одно слово: [`'~{(\w+)}~u'`](https://regex101.com/r/ciV633/4)
- Между `{...}` может быть очень много вложенных фигурных скобок: [`'~{((?:[^{}]++|(?R))*)}~'`](https://regex101.com/r/ciV633/5) (тут выражение находит `{`, после которой следует 0 и более повторов 1+ знаков, отличных от `{` и `}`, или самого шаблона целиком (т.е. рекурсивно ищет вхождения всего шаблона), а затем закрывающую `}`).

Обратите внимание, что модификатор `u` нужен в тех случаях, когда необходима поддержка строк Юникода.

Теперь, как эти выражения использовать? В PHP есть две основные функции для извлечения текста с помощью регулярного выражения, [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) (ищет *первое* совпадение) и [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php) (ищет *все непересекающиеся* совпадения). В данном случае необходимо использовать вторую функцию:

```
$s='my {zip} i {ooi} o {тут
новая строка} {отлично, да!}  {ну {да!}
{Вот это {Вот это {Вот это } да!} нет!}';
if (preg_match_all('~{([^{}]*)}~', $s, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
// => Array ( [0] => zip [1] => ooi [2] => тут
//   новая строка [3] => отлично, да! [4] => да! [5] => Вот это )
```

[См. PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/Ib8JkX)

- `$matches[0]` содержит все найденные совпадения, вместе со скобками.
- `$matches[1]` содержит все значения, захваченные первой захватываемой группой, которая задана в каждом из вышеперечисленных регулярных выражений, т.е. весь текст внутри скобок.

Answer (score 2):

Вот этой регуляркой можете взять то что вам нужно.

```
#\{(.*?)\}#m
```

А пример работы регулярки можете смотреть [тут](https://regex101.com/r/SqDccx/1/).

Эта регулярка берет все что будет в ковычках (`{}`)

Пример работы на `php`

```
<?php 
  $string = 'My {si-te}';
  $pattern = '/\{(.*?)\}/m';
  preg_match($pattern, $string, $m);
  print_r($m);
?>
```

Результат.

```
Array
(
  [0] => {si-te}
  [1] => si-te
)
```

Comment: похоже что вы позабыли `$replacement = '$2';` в результате манипуляций с `preg_replace()` :)

Comment: @Эдуард Нет я результат показывал, а не код писал в место автора.

Comment: то есть `$replacement` написано не вами? Просто запись вида `'$2'` явно тут лишняя, т.к. в `preg_match()` она никак не может участвовать.

Comment: @Эдуард Да я написал? в чем проблема? что код `preg_replace` не дописал? не кто не мешает вам дать свой ответ.

Comment: проблем нет, просто ваш пример выглядит не корректно.

Comment: @Эдуард Ок спасибо

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/lGIgBZ/2

`\{\w+\}` - в принципе, этой регулярки должно хватить.

Comment: В имени сайта может быть например и `-`. Тогда ваша регулярка уже не работает. `My {si-te}`  вот пример смотрите.